# How do I get my Profile Picture in my Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story, profile-picture

I just received an email regarding the new functionality "Developer Story".

I just configured everything, but I noticed that the profile picture at the story view is not showing up, why is that? I have a profile picture on my account.

Do I need to configure it anywhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *explicitly indicate* that you want to use your profile picture. After all, a lot of users use randomly generated gravatars, unicorns or something else than a photo of themselves. That's fine for a website, but not so professional for a resume.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, can you give further details about where do I explicitly indicate that?

Comment: Thanks for your edit answer, I just notice now the edit function on chrome browser at my desktop. I was using my tablet and was not seeing that button!

Comment: @TiagoM indeed, you only see it when hovering. That's kind of hard on a tablet.

Comment: You are right @Glorfindel ! Now I got it covered :) thanks to you! have a great day!